# RabbitMQ impacting JDBC connection pool

Tags: java, jdbc, rabbitmq

I have a web servlet that has been running well. I decided to replace a TCP connection to a backend server with RabbitMQ. While doing some load testing I noticed that it quickly started to fail with timeouts waiting for idle JDBC connection.

```
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-12] JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(234) | Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-12] JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(225) | Cannot open connection [???]
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:114)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:560)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:438)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:261)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at net.hedtech.degreeworks.security.service.ShpPassportService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9c441f05.getAndCheckPassportForRequest(<generated>)
    at net.hedtech.degreeworks.security.spring.ShpPassportFilter.doFilter(ShpPassportFilter.java:124)
    at net.hedtech.degreeworks.security.spring.ShpPassportFilter$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8067e598.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
    at com.sungardhe.degreeworks.util.SpringBeansProfiler.aroundAdvice(SpringBeansProfiler.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor167.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at net.hedtech.degreeworks.security.spring.ShpPassportFilter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c08501d.doFilter(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1174)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
```

I have not implemented any pooling myself at this point. The RabbitMQ connection is a singleton shared between all the session threads. A channel is opened and closed for each request.

My research has not turned up any connection between RabbitMQ and jdbc connection pools, but I have to admit that I only have a passing knowledge of either.

Here is the code I am using:

```
String requestQueueName = "dw-dev-prototype";

QueueingConsumer consumer;

Channel channel = null;
String correlationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
String thisResponse = null;
String totalResponse = "";
StringBuffer sbResponse;
// We will create a new reply queue for each request
String replyQueueName = "";

try
{
   // We will send the replyQueueName with the request so the server knows how to send the
   // response back to us
   channel = _connection.createChannel();
   replyQueueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();
   consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
   channel.basicConsume(replyQueueName, AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE, consumer);
   BasicProperties props = new BasicProperties.Builder().correlationId(correlationId).replyTo(replyQueueName)
      .build();
   channel.basicPublish(NO_EXCHANGE, requestQueueName, props, sNameValuePairs.getBytes("UTF-8"));
}
catch (IOException e)
{
   log.error("New connection IOException: " + e.getMessage(), e);
   abortConnection(_connection, channel);
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

while (true)
{
   QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery;
   try
   {
      // Get the next response
      delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
      thisResponse = new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8");
      // Ignore the response if it is not for our correlation-id
      else if (delivery.getProperties().getCorrelationId().equals(correlationId))
      {
         if (thisResponse.equals(this._serviceFinishedMsg))
         {
            // No more text for this response - we are done
            break;
         }
         else
         {
            totalResponse += thisResponse;
         }
      }
   }
   catch (ShutdownSignalException | ConsumerCancelledException | InterruptedException e)
   {
      log.error("Consumer exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
   catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
   {
      log.error("UnsupportedEncoding exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }

}

// Close now that we are done
try
{
   if (channel != null && channel.isOpen())
   {
      channel.close();
   }
}
catch (IOException | TimeoutException e)
{
   log.error("Error closing channel or connection", e);
}
```

I am running this in a Tomcat container. I am using Spring, but not Spring AMQP yet.

The JDBC calls are in a security filter that runs before the request gets to this method.

Any hints as to how I might troubleshoot this would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A call that you initiated invoked aop -> spring service -> hibernate. Hibernate is invoking commons dbcp and asking for a connection pool. You're likely running out of connections from this pool or the db has become unreachable. I'd vote for the former.

Integration [java melody](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki) into your app and deploy it again. Monitor the connection pool and check if you run out. If you do...

- Consider increasing the connection pool limit
- If increasing connection pool limit does not help, you might have a dbcp pool leak. Investigate if you are returning connections back to the pool correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Deepak. Certainly, that is where we are running out of connections. However, that part of the application didn't change, so the question is - why did the introduction of RabbitMQ suddenly make such a difference.

Thanks for the hint about java melody. I'll look into that.

Comment: I can't tell without looking at your application, but my guess would be that your consumers are processing messages at a rate that the connection pool cannot keep up with. Since the connections are drained here, any request for new connections from ANY part of the web app will fail. Take a look at [spring listener containers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html), which can cap this. This is only a hunch based on the information we have on this post.

Comment: Deepak, again thank you. I will look at the Spring listener container. I was planning on using Spring's message support in any case. I'm just trying to understand a little more about RabbitMQ before I do.

So, are you saying that each of my consumers are using a connection from the same pool as the JDBC connections? That would certainly explain this, yes. At what point does this happen? During consumer creation (`new QueueingConsumer1`)? I will test this.